# 2 types of Login in AWS Cognito

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I want your opinion for my project so want to discuss some basic requirement of my project.

My app has 2 types of Login

1) Agent Login

2) User Login

Every user has one agent, without agent id user can not signup and one agent has many users.

> **I want both these types of login by using AWS Cognito, and want to**
>   **maintain users and agents in dynamoDB.**
>
> **User table has AgentId as a column and all details of the user(email,**
>   **name, pictures etc) and using dynamoDB, I'll create serverless APIs**

Hope you get the rough idea about the project

How I can create user pool for both Agents and Users (linked to each other)

Can you please discuss and share some stuff and links so that I can proceed further.

Answer (score 1):

You need custom lambda  to add and verify your logic as cognito authorizer only validate token .

Add pre  trigger in your cognito pool and add your logic to authetication and authorization.

Create one user pool and in your mapping table define your role and based on your mapping table in trigger validate your users.

You can also associate your IAM role with user so it's your choices and logic.

Following link is my notes may be helpful

https://github.com/vaquarkhan/vaquarkhan/wiki/AWS-Custom-Lambda-authorizer---authentication-for-amazon-api-gateway-for-microservice

Answer (score 0):

In user pool you can create 2 groups - Agents and Users. Create 2 different roles for each and attach the policies you want. You can then allow [Role Level access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_dynamodb_rows.html) to dynamoDB for users based on their cognito ID. Make sure you add AgentID as a field in dynamoDB so that your one to many agent to users relationship is maintained.

You can also save information in Cognito User pools. You can create custom fields as well so you can even skip using dynamodb.